# Use DynamoDB as Laravel cache

Tags: laravel, amazon-dynamodb

I'd like to use a DynamoDB table for my Laravel cache. I added https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb to the project, but now I have no clue regarding how to configure Laravel to use DynamoDB, what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read instructions: https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb#usage ?

Comment: Sure, but unfortunately there are no reference about the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library you refer here is for integrating Eloquent with DynamoDB. They say [here](https://github.com/baopham/laravel-dynamodb/issues/159) you can use it and write your own cache driver.

**But** Laravel 5.8 (as per the [release notes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/releases)) has it's own DynamoDB cache driver so I would use that instead. Please check the `config/cache.php` [file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.8.17/config/cache.php) where you can find a 'dynamodb' store which looks quite straightforward to configure.

Comment: BTW, slightly related, we've moved all of our Laravel caching and session storage from DynamoDB to Redis (on ElastiCache) due to performance. Redis was 10x faster on early benchmarks when compared to DynamoDB.